# Override Ngrx/data data service urls

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I'm trying to use ngrx/data with my api.
My api exposes resources under the format /resources for all requests instead of POST /resource (without 's'). Same for GET /resources/:id instead of /resource/:id as required by ngrx/data.

How can I force the data service to hit /resources for all requests?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might use an entity-metadata.ts files with following content:

```
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  ressources: {}
};

const pluralNames = {
  ressources: 'ressources'
};

export const entityConfig = {
  entityMetadata,
  pluralNames,
};
```

In your module you need an import with:

```
EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig)
```

Comment: It is also possible to provide a custom HttpUrlGenerator as written in the docs: https://ngrx.io/guide/data/extension-points#replace-the-httpurlgenerator